# MySQL join query and sum record

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write JOIN query with 4 Tables. I need query to return total SUM of profit getting by their clients. Added below the Table Structure, required result.

**user_profile**

detail of all user in the system

```
---------------------
|   ID    | user_id |  
---------------------
|   1     | 1001    |
|   2     | 1002    |
|   3     | 1003    |
|   4     | 1004    |
---------------------
```

**manager_client**

this table is use to differentiate between manager and client under him/her

```
----------------------------
|manager_id   | client_id  |
----------------------------
|   1001      | 1002       | 
|   1001      | 1003       | 
|   1001      | 1004       | 
----------------------------
```

**client_trans**

this table store the information about transaction perform by client based on `login_id`

```
---------------------------
|user_id    |   login_id  |
---------------------------
|   1002    |   1         | 
|   1002    |   2         | 
|   1002    |   3         | 
---------------------------
```

**trans_history**

this table store information about client's profit based on `login_id`, different `login_id` will generate different profit

```
-----------------------
|login_id  |    profit |
-----------------------
|   1002    |   10     | 
|   1002    |   20     | 
|   1002    |   30     | 
-----------------------
```

-this is the expected result look like

```
----------------------------------
| user_id |  profit              |
----------------------------------
| 1001    | totalprofitallclient |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_id SUM(t.profit)
FROM user_profile u NATURAL JOIN client_trans c NATURAL JOIN trans_history t
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

I don't see why the 4th table is needed.

Explanation: Join all the tables naturally (meaning e.g. user_profile will be joined with client_trans over the 'user_id' column.)
Then group all transactions with the same user_id.
Lastly add up all the profits.

Edit: If user_id in client_trans actually means the master_id, then you would have to change the statement to the following:

```
SELECT u.user_id SUM(t.profit)
FROM user_profile u JOIN manager_client m ON u.user_id = m.client_id JOIN client_trans c ON m.master_id = c.user_id NATURAL JOIN trans_history t
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: You don't even need the table `user_profile`, if you don't care about users that have no profit.

Comment: @Pharaoh oh right, thank you. Was just blindly trying to form an answer that joins 4 tables.